# Constraining the range of decision variables based on other decision variables

Tags: excel, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I have a regular classroom assignment problem with course sizes and class capacities. Decision variables are binary. The model allows assigning one course to more than one room as long as the total capacity assigned is bigger than the course size. The constraint I want to add to this model is to make sure that the respective sizes of the rooms assigned to each course are within a reasonable range (say 20 seats) from **each other**. How can this be done in a linear way? How can I prevent the model from assigning a course of 60 students to 2 rooms of 10 and 50 capacities and instead make sure their sizes are close together (preferably even equal).

I'm using Excel with OpenSolver.

---

Here's some sample data:

```
Course/Room   324A   321D   124B   328   Course Size   Capacity Assigned   Wasted
Management     0      0      0      1        15               25             10
Engineering    1      0      0      0        20               20              0
Science        0      1      1      0        60               75             15

Room Sizes    20     40     35     25
```

The objective is to minimize the total space wasted (which is 25 seats in this example).

Comment: it is pretty hard to answer this in any way without some sample data. also, this site is more for stuff like debugging. So have you done already anything? Is there anything you could show so we know where to start?

Comment: This is more of a modeling question so I guess OR-Exchange (https://www.or-exchange.org/) would be more suitable. You can try minimizing the maximum deviations from a constant for each course.

Comment: @ayhan Yes, a minmax formulation should be interesting to try. Substituting a deviation from a constant (instead of from other decision variables) was what I needed. Thank you very much!

Comment: @DirkReichel I've added a very short example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce variables `minseat` and `maxseat` and form the inequalities:

```
minseat(course) <= seats(room)+(1-assign(course,room))*M
maxseat(course) >= seats(room)-(1-assign(course,room))*M
maxseat(course)-minseat(course) <= 20
```

Alternatively put `maxseat(course)-minseat(course)` in the objective with some cost factor. Choose `M` judiciously.

Comment: This makes perfect sense!